# How to call and send a string to Tab List Fragment from fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have 3 tabs with List Fragments('A','B' and 'C') and also have Navigation Drawer list that contains a list of data for filtering the content of the lists in the 3 tabs. What i want is that when i click on any item in Navigation Drawer list, the current tab content should refresh and should show new data in the list. If lets say we are in Tab A and select any item from Navigation Drawer, how do we send a string to Tab A, so that Tab A list content is refreshed?

Fragment Activity

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.clip1);

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE); 
    setTitle("Records");

    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){



        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }};
        //Add New Tab

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("A").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("B").setTabListener(tabListener));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("C").setTabListener(tabListener));

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    CategoryDatabaseHandler dbcategory = new CategoryDatabaseHandler(this);
    categoryList=dbcategory.getCategoryList();
    DrawerItemCustomAdapter drawerAdapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, categoryList);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                    long arg3) 
              {
                //actionBar.selectTab(actionBar.getSelectedTab());
              }
        });
```

Listfragment

```
MySimpleArrayAdapter myadapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this.getActivity(),AList);

       setListAdapter(myadapter);

       ListView listView = getListView();


       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/3276104) out. You can register the LocalBroadcastManager listener to the fragment that you want and then from your MainActivity when an item is selected from the navigation drawer you will send a message to your fragment so it can refresh it's contend